# How to generate a list of checkboxes in SAPUI5 from OData service in XML view?

Tags: sapui5

Dear SAPUI5 developers,

How can we generate a list of checkbox items from an OData Service in XML View?

For example in the following I made a drop down SELECT from an OData service. Is it possible to do something like this with checkbox in `XML` View?

```
<sap.ui.layout.form:FormElement label="{i18n>PartnerName}">
    <sap.ui.layout.form:fields>
        <Select items="{path: '/BusinessPartnerSet', sorter: { path: 'McName1', descending: false } }">
            <core:Item key="{Partner}" text="{McName1}"/>
        </Select>
    </sap.ui.layout.form:fields>
</sap.ui.layout.form:FormElement>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible. I'm doing it for JSON model, you can similarly try for oDataModel-

**Model**:

```
    var data = [
                {
                    value:"Oranges",
                    selected:false
                },
                {
                    value:"Apples",
                    selected:true
                },
                {
                    value:"Mango",
                    selected:false
                },
                {
                    value:"Grapes",
                    selected:true
                },
                {
                    value:"Watermelons",
                    selected:false
                },
                {
                    value:"Bananas",
                    selected:false
                }

                ];

    this.getView().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data));
```

**XML View:**

```
    <VBox items="{/}" >
        <items>
            <CheckBox text='{value}' selected='{selected}' />
        </items>
    </VBox>
```

Comment: One more question: Is it also possible to set value for these checkboxes?

I want to set the id of the odata elements as the value of the checkboxes.

Comment: @MahdiJaberzadeh : I don't think I fully understand what you asked. Is ID an field in OData Entity set ? If yes, then you can easily do it like this :  `<CheckBox text='{ID}' selected='{selected}' />`. ID will be shown as Text with a CheckBox.

Comment: Yes Id is part of the odata service, but I want just to show the name, but have the ID as the value of each textbox. I don't want to show the id as the name. If I have some similar text then I need to know which one was selected. While ID is unique. Also in HTML it is possible to set different value for each checkbox.

Comment: @MahdiJaberzadeh: You will need to create CustomData for each Checkbox to store a different value then what is shown in screen. Check this link : https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f0c3ee6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html
Change in VIEW XML:
`<CheckBox name='CB' text='{textToDisplay}'  selected='{selected}' >
     <customData>
      <core:CustomData key='value' value='{value}' writeToDom='true'>
      </core:CustomData>
     </customData>
     </CheckBox>`

Fetch Checkbox value using:
`sap.ui.getCore().byId('id_of_checkbox').data('value');`

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Actually I found out that when I retrieve the checkbox element with sap.ui.getCore().byId('id_of_checkbox') I can reach the Odata object that the checkbox is related to that. but you solution is also good.